# Automatically export Parse data?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, export, parse-cloud-code

So we all know that we can manually export a Parse class by pressing the button in the data browser but is there some JavaScript code that can be used to make a Cloud Function/Job that export's the data for us?

Comment: Me also, I might get going to on-writing one, will update